# copy data from selected sheet to another new row in another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to achieve the following:

in HR he is entering data for each new candidate in one sheet, these data is mainly the cost on a monthly and yearly basis.

What he is looking for is to have an *add button* where he can add some selected data into another sheet to create some sort of report, so whenever he adds new data it will be stored in a new line in the other sheet.

Comment: Without looking at your code, it would be very difficult to find out what the issue is. Please provide what you have tried so far and where the issue is in your code. Also, a snapshot of the sheet and what the end result should look like. This will help us to identify the issue.

Comment: i dont have a code to start with, i am not good at VBA coding, my friend told me i can do it with VBA
basically in sheet "EcE"
i have employee name, title, basic salary, housing, etc... in cell D4,D5, D6, etc... what i want it to copy these data into another sheet "Report" in a row format, and then when i click Add again it will add another data (same fields) in a new row

Answer (score 1):

try this. you say each new candidate in one sheet. so your data at you can see in macro  is in "Ece" sheet at range (E4:E7), because you say it is in D4:D6..). its just make copy and then paste in sheet Report in second row with transpose function. When you clicking add again it is copy and paste one row below in Report sheet. it works if your data is only for one candidate in sheet.

```
    Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
Sheets("EcE").Select
    Range("E4:E7").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Report").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    lMaxRows = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range("A" & lMaxRows + 1).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=True
    Range("A1").Select



End Sub
```

Comment: thanks @skimante Valentaite


i want to copy D8 to B5, D9 to C5, D15 to H5 E15 to Q5, D23 to N5 and so on..... i have some structure in the first entry sheet that should be in a row format in the other sheet, i have around 23 cells that in one sheet i want to copy to another sheet in a specific format, not like Range("E4: E12)


so for example, as above, they will start from row 5 in my report sheet and go on

Comment: D8 is in EcE sheet,        B5 is in Report sheet